Time Machine OSStatus-Error 80 (English)
I deleted MacBook Pro's disk, reinstall of Sonoma, Time Machine Backup is on a Synology DS
My Time Machine Backups are password protected  with the mechanism used by MacOS or Time Machine itself. I put in the wrong password when trying to add the Time Machine Volume. First it gave me something like "wrong password" and then it gave me the error in the title.
How can I access this password-protected backup?

Answer OP included in the question:

I had to delete the Entry "<my-macbooks-name-.sparsebundle>" inside the Keychain in "System". Only after that I could add the Volume with the correct password."

